# Allowing an invalid state before an entity creation process is completed?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, domain-objects

A lot of sites will save the progress of the creation of an entity or some process. For example, stackoverflow will allow you to draft a question before you post it. If StackOverflow used DDD, I would assume that the `Question` entity would only be valid if it had 1) a body and 2) a title. So there must be some precursor entity that enables them to save our input to these fields - perhaps a `QuestionDraft` or `DraftQuestion` which captures selected tags, the title and body but also allows them to be null. I would further guess that there is some factory method, perhaps on the `QuestionDraft` or `Question` entity itself to attempt to create a `Question` from a `QuestionDraft`.

```
class Question {
    ...

    public static Question FromDraft(QuestionDraft draft) {
        // check to ensure all required fields are not null
        // If any are null, raise exception or Err result
        return Question(draft.id, draft.title, draft.body, draft.tags)
    }
}
```

This is all well and good when you have a `Post your question` button which acts as the trigger for converting a draft to a complete entity with full validation.

My question is very close to this process, except we leave out the button to `Post your question`. There are some domains where we simply want to create the entity as soon as it is valid to do so - it is ok to have an invalid entity until the moment it becomes a valid entity, then it must be valid forever onwards.

The issue with this is that instead of checking to see if its ok to post on a single button - single endpoint, we need to check upon every single update to a draft. When we are talking about entities with 3-6 different steps in creation, every state altering request to a draft will need to 1) check if it is completed, if it is, create the final object and delete itself. That doesn't sound very DRY to me.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Repeated calls to a `validate()` method are not DRY enough for you? I can assure you that many extremely successful libraries and frameworks do just that.

Comment: @KilianFoth I'm simply wondering if there is a better way. I don't mean to say that its a bad method at all, especially because it will likely be contained to a small area - only the draft. So, I guess `questionDraft.IsCompleteQuestion()` and `Question.FromDraft(questionDraft)` in each command involving a change in state of the question draft is ok. Thanks!

Comment: `DRY` means, don't repeat the validation code in every single place you need it. Just write it once and reuse it. How many times you call that code only matters if you are paranoic about efficiency. Or if the validation consumes a lot of computational resources. And yet, you can call it more than once in the data's lifecycle if you deem it necessary.